# Could someone give me an example of MaxSat's approximable 1/2 algorithm?

Tags: maxsat

in my Complexity class I have to present the 1/2 **MaxSat approximation algorithm** that appears in the Vazirani, Vijay V - Approximation algorithms-Spring (2011) [Image attached].
The problem is that it is not clear to me where and how the **weights** are assigned. The example talks about considering the weights as a unit but I don't understand why. Could someone give me a small **example of the execution of the algorithm**[image]?

Thank you

Comment: The weights are part of the instance. If your instance is unweighted, you can assume that they are all $1$.

Comment: Oh  I see , so in that case (unweighted) I just consider the probability of each clause, thank ou.

Answer (score 0):

The weights are provided as part of the instance: each clause is accompanied by one.

In the unweighted case, you can think of each clause as having unit weight.